# Regex to validate username not working

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
/^[A-z0-9\._-]{3,24}+$/i
```

This is supposed to only match a string between 3 and 24 characters long, and only with the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and then also the . _ and - characters.

The problem is this is also matching strings like "^_^". Someone just created a username with exactly that, so this is definitely a problem! Can anyone spot the problem with my regex?

Comment: According to [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/38vvt), your pattern has a syntax error; strange why PCRE doesn't seem to care about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/^[\w.-]{3,24}$/
```

`A-z` is not same as `[A-Za-z]` as it also includes other characters such as `^` (thanks Jack)

Also remove extra quantifier `+` after `{3,24}` which means one or more instances of whole string.

**PS:** I have also shortened your regex to use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: Awesome. Nice and simple! Thanks. I have to wait a couple more minutes before I can accept the answer.

Comment: Actually, the `+` has no ill effects (even though it shouldn't be there). What you have "masked" as shortening the regex *is* actually the fix, because the `A-z` range includes `^` :)

Comment: @Jack: Thanks I overlooked that part, added in my answer.

Comment: wow, i thought A-z was a-z and A-Z. are all the special characters included in A-z?

Comment: `A-z` includes all characters in the range from 65 to 122 in ASCII table

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `+` as you are specifying a range of lengths with the `{3,24}`

```
/^[A-z0-9\._-]{3,24}$/i
```

As was pointed out in the comments below, `A-z` matches the ^ character, as well. In this case `A-Za-z` would be better; however, the answer above with `\w.-` is the most elegant by far.

Comment: This still matches `"^_^"`.

Comment: You are correct, I should not have used A-z in this case, rather A-Za-z. But, frankly, I consider @anubhava's answer more elegant anyway.